# Merge two ArrayLists of Custom Object Type

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to combine two ArrayList into a single one. These ArrayLists are NOT the type of "String". Object type is a custom class.

```
private ArrayList<NewsItem> newsList;
private ArrayList<NewsItem> eventList;
private ArrayList<NewsItem> combinedList;
```

This is how I am trying to combine those two ArrayLists:

```
private void combineArrays() {

    if(newsList.size() > 0){
        for (int i = 0; i<newsList.size(); i++){

            NewsItem aBean = newsList.get(i);
            combinedList.add(aBean);
        }
    }
    if(eventList.size() > 0){
        for (int i = 0; i<eventList.size(); i++){
            NewsItem aBean = eventList.get(i);
            combinedList.add(aBean);;
        }
    }
}
```

The app is crashing. What's the wrong with this approach?

Comment: you missed the new operator on your lists: `newsList = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @Blackbelt Why should I use newsList = new ArrayList<>();? newsList and evenList are NOT empty when it comes to private void combineArrays() method

Comment: I see only the declaration of these objects, never their initialisation. Can you  post the stacktrace

Comment: @sajaz It doesnt matter if your existing lists are not empty. What matters is that you want to create a new list to combine the other two lists. This **new** list must be created before you can use it. Therefore you need a **new** somewhere. (Unless you would want to append list B to existing list A)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that simpler...

```
combinedList = new ArrayList<NewsItem>();
if (newsList != null)
  combinedList.addAll( newsList );
if (eventList!= null)
  combinedList.addAll( eventList);
```

If you don't want to have duplicates (implies you have implemented equals() correctly) then you could use a HashSet, for example, but that implies you don't need a specific order of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **addAll()** method as:

```
combinedList.addAll(newsList);
combinedList.addAll(eventList);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new list :

```
 ArrayList<NewsItem> combinedList = new ArrayList();
 combinedList.addAll(newsList);
 combinedList.addAll(eventList);
```

too late ..